# Making a playable maze in ms Excel: Disabling a button when in a specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

Am currently making a maze game IN MS Excel and I have made my buttons 'up', 'down','left','right' and gave it an offset command (located in the module), I'm thinking of disabling specific buttons for when the cell is cornered by a wall (cannot go left or right, etc.)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim b1, b2, b3, b4 As Button
        Set b1 = ActiveSheet.Buttons("Up").up_Click
        Set b2 = ActiveSheet.Buttons("Down").down_click
        Set b3 = ActiveSheet.Buttons("Left").left_click
        Set b4 = ActiveSheet.Buttons("Right").right_click
            If Selection.Count = 1 Then
             If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AF9")) Is Nothing Then
                    b1.Enabled = False
                    b2.Enabled = True
                    b3.Enabled = False
                    b4.Enabled = False
                
             End If
        End If
End Sub
```

I tried this code (located in the sheet; not in the module) so that the buttons will disable but I am getting an error message saying "Run-time error '1004': Unable to get Buttons properly of the Worksheet class" then it highlights the code `Set b1 = ActiveSheet.Buttons("Up").up_Click`. I don't know what to change in the code. (If you guys want to suggest a different way in making the walls, please feel free :D)

Comment: One thing to note is right now you have `b1`, `b2` and `b3` declared as `Variant` - that `Dim` line should be `Dim b1 as Button, b2 as Button, b3 as Button, b4 As Button`.

Comment: Also I'm not sure what `.up_Click` is - is that a property of these buttons?

Comment: oh i read something here "https://www.contextures.com/excelformcontrolbuttons.html"  saying "ActiveSheet.Buttons("Button 1").Name"  so im assuming that the '.name' is the name of the macro?

Comment: No `.Name` is the literal property of `.Buttons()` - You should be able to just assign each button with `Set b1 = ActiveSheet.Buttons("Up")`, not need for a `.Name` or anything else.

Comment: oh okay.. i just removed the .Name and the error is still popping up

Comment: When you select your button on the worksheet, what name is showing up in the box in the top left hand corner?

Comment: oh, when i click the buttons there are no text written in the the top left hand corner; the msg just pops up

Comment: I mean when you're in developer mode - are you sure you've renamed the buttons from their default names, Button 1, Button 2 etc.?

Comment: oh name appears when you ctrl+click,, yeah it has the default name.. i changed it already and there's no error; however the macro doesnt seem to work? i dont know if the code should be placed in the module or the sheet, or in the code of the button

Answer (score 1):

Worksheets don't have a `.Buttons()` collection, and buttons don't have an `up_Click` event handler.

It sounds like you are using actual button controls (as opposed to using cells that look like buttons). You can enable and disable an ActiveX Button Control, but not a Form Button Control. There is a difference. If you are using Form Button Controls on the worksheet then you will need to replace them with ActiveX Button Controls. If you name the buttons "CommandButton_up", "CommandButton_down", "CommandButton_right", and "CommandButton_left", then in the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` you can disable them like so:

```
CommandButton_up.Enabled = False
CommandButton_down.Enabled = False
CommandButton_right.Enabled = False
CommandButton_left.Enabled = False
```

You will of course need more logic surrounding when and how you disable them, but this is how you interact with an ActiveX control located on a worksheet.